# How to nest object data in Vue CLI3 with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

In plain js we could write:

```
data() {
  return {
    form: {
      name: '',
      password: ''
    }
  }
}
```

But how to achieve this using typescript (vue-property-decorator)? I've read this should be implemented using interfaces, like that:

```
interface Form {
  name: string
  password: string
}

@Component
export default class Login extends Vue {
  // how to use interface here?
}
```

I'm using this as `v-model` on input:

`<input v-model="form.email">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class component can have a property `form` which is of type `Form`

```
interface Form {
  name: string
  password: string
}

@Component
export default class Login extends Vue {
  form:Form = {name: '', password: ''}
}
```

Didn't test this though!

**EDIT**

An example of an interface that uses interfaces itself

```
interface Form {
   users : User[]
   password : string
}

interface User {
   name : string
   id : number
}

let form : Form = {
   users: [
     { name:"Ren", id:3 },
     { name:"Stimpy", id:43 }
   ],
   password: ''
}
```

Comment: It works, indeed. Could you explain a bit deeper - interfaces are just my like custom types? What if i wanted to nest 1 level deeper?

Comment: Yes, interfaces are used as custom types, and you can let Classes subscribe to interfaces too. If your Form contains sub objects you can just make interfaces for those too. I edited the answer with an example.